# What do shape of universe mean?

Tags: universe

What shape does a three dimensional universe have ? and how did scientists determined that it is flat and not curved.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't a clue what your question is about. Would you please care to clarify what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: @TildalWave I interpret it in terms of curvature - i.e. "How is the universe curved?" I think that would be a duplicate of something, though.

Comment: @HDE226868 It would take about one minute off OP's time, and about 20+ minutes off each attempting to answer it whilst not being sure about its nature. I'd suggest that the former is the better option. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's useful to realize the meaning of "shape" is not the same as in "what is the shape of this object I'm holding." Because we are a part of the universe, "shape" is about how things work (eg, how light moves through the universe), rather than "is the universe a sphere, cube, hypersphere or some other 'shape'."

This question is probably too broad to be answered here. I suggest reading the [WikiPedia article on the 'Shape of the Universe'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe).